# Image Size for Mobile - WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile

I have an issue with the below link when viewing from mobile.
http://www.empowerhealthconcepts.com.au/rubix-plyometrics/

All of the other links like the below one for example the image size are Ok on Mobile view.
http://www.empowerhealthconcepts.com.au/chronic-disease-management-and-prevention/

The only difference is that for the Rubix Plyometrics page I have added a class on the images to center, space them out and separate them.

The class is:

```
.rubiximage {
margin-left: 105px;
width: 21% !important;
}
```

If i do not put width 21% then the images get cut off on mobile view.
But when i put 21% the images appear too small on mobile view.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove your code and use this:

```css
.rubiximage {
    float: left;
    max-width: 270px;
    width: 100%;
}
.entry-content p:first-child{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Instead of 50% width it should be 100% but your images are too small and if you use 100% they will look pixelated.

Comment: Unfortunately using that CSS makes my images way to big and prevent them from being on one line as they currently are

Comment: Then remove the width: 50% and use float left.

Comment: They are not staying on the same line because of their size, you said that they looked to small. They will break at a certain resolution if you want them to look good on mobile. See my updated answer.